# align double map function

Tags: mapping

i need write this map with this align.

[image: map align]
i've tried this but is wrong

```
   \begin{align*}
\psi\colon A&\longrightarrow& B(D) \\
T&\longmapsto&\hat{T} \\
&&  \hat{T}\colon D     &\longrightarrow        \mathbb{C}   \\ 
S          &&&\longmapsto      \hat{T}(S)
\end{align*}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `alignat` to set another alignment point and then a nested `aligned`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\psi\colon A&\rightarrow {}&& B(D) \\
           T&\mapsto     {}&& \hat{T} \\
&&&\begin{aligned}
  \hat{T}\colon D &\rightarrow \mathbb{C}   \\
                S &\mapsto     \hat{T}(S)
\end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excellent, thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

A solution is an `alignedat` environment nested in  `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\psi\colon A&\longrightarrow B(D) \\
T&\longmapsto \begin{alignedat}[t]{2} & \hat{T} \\
& \hat{T} & \colon D& \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
 & & S& \longmapsto \hat{T}(S)
\end{alignedat}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]